# child class of CListCtrl cannot refresh display but still active

Tags: mfc, c++17, refresh, clistctrl

I'm coding an app, using C++17 standards and graphical library MFC.
I have two virtual classes, ViewerGet and ViewerSet, that both inherit from Viewer class, that inherits from CListCtrl class from MFC. My problem is about ViewerGet, built as such :

```
void ViewerGet::InitViewer(CWnd* pParent, CRect oWndRect)
{
    if (!Create(WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA, oWndRect, pParent, 0))
        return;

    // Set a Global Style + add tips
    SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_INFOTIP | LVS_EX_LABELTIP);
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(*pParent, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES);

    // Columns Creation
    LPTSTR lpszCols[] = { _T("Variable name"),_T("Variable path"),_T("Value read"),_T("Validity"),_T("Recording"),_T("Type"),0};
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);
    int columnSize[] = { int(rect.Width() * 0.3), int(rect.Width() * 0.45), int(rect.Width() * 0.12), int(rect.Width() * 0.07), int(rect.Width() * 0.03) };
    LV_COLUMN   lvColumn;
    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

    for (int x = 0; lpszCols[x] != NULL; x++)
    {
        lvColumn.pszText = lpszCols[x];
        lvColumn.cx = columnSize[x];
        InsertColumn(x, &lvColumn);
    }

    m_arrowImage.Create(IDB_LOGO_LIST, 24, 0, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SetImageList(&m_arrowImage, LVSIL_SMALL);
}
```

When I try to put data in my ViewerGet, I follow those steps :

1. Select lines in yet another CListCtrl
2. Right click to make pop-up window appear
3. Click on the button "Add to ViewerGet"
   Then, the relevant lines are added to my ViewerGet. Up until now, everything is OK.

However, when I then want to select lines in ViewerGet, 3 possible behaviors :

- Everything works out normally (I can select, remove, check checkboxes...)
- The ViewerGet is instantly frozen (when I click on a line, it's not selected as it should)
- The ViewerGet starts out normally, but at one point (which one, I wasn't able to pinpoint it), it freezes again
  I noticed that when I minimise + maximise my window, the ViewerGet is refreshed, once. But no more after that.
  This does not happens with ViewerSet, the other child class, only with ViewerGet
  I don't think it's important, but ViewerGet is supposed to receive & refresh data every 50ms, received from a CAN bus. This does not seem important as the ViewerGet freeze happens even if I'm not receiving data, even if I have no CAN bus plugged in...

Here is the method called when chosing to add a line to the ViewerGet table :

```
void AppDlg::OnEditOnLeftTab()
{
    m_oTabViewer.SetCurSel(0);
    OnSelchangeTabViewer(NULL, NULL);

    m_poViewGet->LockWindowUpdate();

    EnterCriticalSection(database.GetMutex());

    std::vector<IascVariable*> selVars = m_list.GetSelectedVariables();
    for (IascVariable* var : selVars)
        if (database.ReadEntryFor(var)==NULL)
            database.AddReadEntry(new ReadEntry(var));
    m_poViewGet->SetItemCount(database.ReadEntriesListCount());

    LeaveCriticalSection(database.GetMutex());
}
```

Expected behavior : just to have my ViewerGet work normally, being refreshed when I need it (click to change selected lines, new value refreshed in relevant column of ViewerGet when CAN communication is OK...)

What I tried :

- Used several CListCtrl styles such as WS_CLIPCHILDREN
- Used LockWindow() and UnlockWindow() methods
- Used SetRedraw(FALSE) and SetRedraw(TRUE) methods
- Verified the data was updated in the background of the display
- Verified OnGetDispInfo notifications :

```
void Viewer::OnGetDispInfo(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO* plvdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*)pNMHDR;
    if (plvdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
        lstrcpyn(plvdi->item.pszText, CellContent(plvdi->item.iItem, plvdi->item.iSubItem), plvdi->item.cchTextMax);
    if (plvdi->item.mask & LVIF_IMAGE)
    {
        plvdi->item.iImage = CellImage(plvdi->item.iItem, plvdi->item.iSubItem);
        plvdi->item.mask |= LVIF_STATE;
        plvdi->item.stateMask |= LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
        plvdi->item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(CheckboxContent(plvdi->item.iItem, plvdi->item.iSubItem));
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

- Tried to force ViewerGet refresh with methods RedrawItems(item,item) (only one line) or even RedrawWindow() for full ViewerGet
- Change OnCustomDraw method :

```
void Viewer::OnCustomDrawBgColor(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    *pResult = 0;
    pLVCD->nmcd.rc.top += 7;
    int nItem = pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
    int nSubItem = pLVCD->iSubItem;

    // what we do next depends on the drawing stage we are processing
    switch (pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
        (...) //other cases, for prepaint mainly    
        case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
                this->RedrawWindow();
        break;

    case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT:;
        this->RedrawWindow();
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT :
I may be wrong, but I don't think this is caused by deadlock. In my understanding, deadlocks would *paralyze* my ViewerGet, however it is still functional, it just... doesn't display want I want it to

Comment: Too many issues to be solved all at once!... My first note is the call of `Create()` in `InitViewer()`. Where and when is `InitViewer()` called? I would rather override the `Create()` method (should include a call to the inherited one), because the framework will always call `Create()`. Second, that `EnterCriticalSection(database.GetMutex());` looks very strange: a database returning a mutex, which is used as a critical section object... the terminology at least is very confusing. --- And Welcome to the Forum.

Comment: `InitViewer()` for ViewerGet and ViewerSet are both called in `AppDlg::InitViewer()`, knowing that AppDlg is a `CDialog` child.

And as for database.GetMutex(), yeah I know it's not quite pretty, sorry. the mutex is a `CRITICAL_SECTION`, yes. It's in database because it's an extern object, so I can access it everywhere. I did it like this because my database is used in several CListCtrl children, and for CAN communication elsewhere... and I wanted to have the same mutex, for everything to go smoothly. It's an old project (2008) that I need to evolve for my internship, hence the clunkiness

Comment: Can you run a small test first? Override `Create()`, in the override call the inherited one and add a `TRACE()` command (or any other logging command, if you are using one and find it more handy). This will tell you if `Create()` is called twice, as I suspect.

Comment: Also, doesn't that `LockWindowUpdate();` need unlocking after you are done?

Comment: This is not, as currently written, an answerable question. Unless you can provide a [mcve], the best we can do is help you diagnose the issue. Seemingly, you are running into a deadlock, where two or more threads are waiting on each other to make forward progress. Deadlocks are a terrifying experience until you realize you've unlocked eternity: Time is no longer a factor in discovering the issue. Open Task Manager, switch to the *"Processes"* tab, identify the hanging process, and run *"Create dump file"* on it.

Comment: With a .dmp file in hand, you can load it up in [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) (or [WinDbg Preview](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windbg-preview/9PGJGD53TN86)), and run [`!analyze -v`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-analyze) or `!analyze -hang` or [`!locks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-locks---kdext--locks-) to gather further details.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Sorry for the `LockWindowUpdate()`, it comes from one of my tests, I forgot to remove it. My test was to see if this `LockWindowUpdate()` at least worked, and well... even when putting it here, half the time my ViewerGet is not blocked, as it should with this instruction.
I'm waiting for approval to install WinDbg as mentionned by @IInspectable.